# Where to find the View object in the object library?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode `Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o)` and I am following this tutorial:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1

which states:

> In your storyboard, use the Object library to find a View object and drag one into your storyboard

However in my object library there is no `view`, there are many of `view controllers` but that is not what I need.

Could you tell me please which view the tutorial wants?

This is an image from the tutorial:

[image]

but I don't have that view here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIView` and all it's variant will be in the Object library. There will be a lot of them, so just type "UIView" or just "View" in the filer textfield below the object library, then you will get the filtered list with the `UIView` object.

[image: Object Library Filtering]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation is calling a view controller a view. So just grab a view controller and drag it into your storyboard.

Comment: i don't think so, because in the section before that sentence, the tutorial told us to create a `UIView` class, not a `ViewController` what do u think?

Comment: and if you noticed the results of adding this *view* object in the tutorial, it is absolutely not a view controller, it is an object under the image.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: In the object library type "view" and scroll down (just for filtering), there will be "UIView" object.

Comment: @MidhunMP thank you i have found it, i didn't know there is a filter there. type an answer to accept it please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Ok great. Sorry I was must have been mistaken. But hope it works out well for you. (: